# what if % is not followed by a suitable character in printf's format string?

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to write a function called error which behaves like printf, but only supports %s, %c and %d specifiers. But I could not understand printf's behavior if % is not followed by a legal character. I also tried to loop up the c99 standard manual but couldn't find anything. Can someone please help me?

Comment: It's not defined in the C standard and in the best case it is implementation-defined (meaning it's documented in you compiler manual). If that's also not the case printf is allowed to order you a pizza or mail some threat mail to your president.. it's just undefined.

Comment: @Mat: That is the answer.You should post it as one.

Comment: I'm interested in the official C standard manual too, so if someone could post a link...

Comment: @MrLister: It's not a "manual", it's the formal definition of the language; therefore it is hard to read, but if you want to have a look, look at the open-std website or this direct link to [n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: @Anthales Thank you! I don't mind "hard to read"; although I have troubles keeping focused when looking at BNF, this is definitely worth it.

Comment: @MrLister: Sorry, but what does BNF stand for?

Comment: @Anthales [Backus–Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus–Naur_Form).

Comment: @MrLister: Ah, never seen that one - doesn't look too bad. The C standard has (as far as I can tell) its own notation, which is similar to BNF, but a bit more intuitive - you'll get it, if you read it.

Answer (score 8):

C99 has this in §7.19.6.1/9 (for `fprintf`):

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.

So a malformed format string leads to undefined behavior.

Same thing if the format string is well formed but the arguments don't actually match the types:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be interested in what *actually* happens, rather than what you *should* be doing as a best practice, I'll address that and leave the others to quote chapter and verse.  :-)

---

The format string is a "hint" to `printf` that tells it how many bytes to process, and how to format them.  If you give it the wrong format, it will happily process the arguments as you told it to, regardless of their actual type.

Depending on the values of those bytes, they may be meaningful, or they may be gibberish.

Here's a simple (implementation-dependent) example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int x = 10; // LF
        x <<= 8;
        x += 13;    // CR
        x <<= 8;
        x += 73;    // I
        x <<= 8;
        x += 72;    // H
        printf("x = %d (%08x)\n", x, x);
        printf("%.4s", &x);
}
```

This defines `x` as a (4-byte, on my system) integer whose bytes contain `10` `13` `73` 72`.  These bytes happen to be the ASCII codes for linefeed, carriage return, I, and H.

The first `printf` displays the decimal and hex values of `x`, and if you calculate them yourself you'll see they're exactly as you'd expect.

But the second `printf` treats `x` as if it were a 4-character string. Since my machine is little-endian it reverses the byte order, so it prints the characters that correspond to ASCII 72, 73, 13, 10, which are

`H` `I` `CR` `LF`

Of course, as Mat noted, this is useful to understand the mechanics behind `printf`, but you shouldn't write code that depends on this behavior.  At the very least, it's not portable (big-endian machines don't change the byte order, for example).

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on how the `printf` is coded. When the `%` is detected in the string the function will find for one of the characters it expects to see. If it matches then it will process the matched block. For example if you pass the `float` to `%d` then it will process the variable you passed an integer in case the arguments are purely passed through stack. Similarly if you pass an `int` to `%f` it will interpret the integer bits as the specific floating point representation of the system.

Also as R.. pointed out in the comment, in the case when the arguments  are passed through registers the output will be different. The type of register on which the passed value is stored (FPU registers or general purpose registers or others). A certain format specifier will pick up the first argument in the register it encounters first.

If the character is something which is not matched say `k` then it may simply print `%k` as the string, or do whatever the function implements.

**EDIT**

Have a look at Mat's answer for the C99 standard specification about the matter.

Comment: This is NOT true: "For example if you pass the float to %d then it will process the variable you passed an integer." It happens that way on some systems that pass all arguments on the stack purely as a result of how the system was implemented. It does NOT happen on systems where the arguments get passed in registers and integer/floating point registers get passed in different register types - x86_64 being the mainstream example. On x86_64, `printf("%g %d", 1, 2.0);` prints `2 1`.

Comment: @R..: I think it is okay now.